# How to step C statements in GDB after going into bootmain() from bootasm.S in xv6?

Tags: c, gdb, bootloader, debug-symbols, xv6

I am using gdb to debug boot loader code in xv6. In `bootasm.S`, I can use gdb to debug assembly code as expected. Then at the end of `bootasm.S`, we will call `bootmain` (line 9168, call bootmain) and the execution will go into the `bootmain` function of the C code bootmain.c. Since it is a C code, I wish to step over the C statements instead of assembly. I know that the `step` command of gdb is for this purpose, but after I input 's', I received an error message: Cannot find bounds of current function. The same error shows up no matter I input 's' before or after the `call bootmain` instruction. So, is it possible to step C statements in gdb when the execution switches from an assembly source to a C source like the situation described above? If it is, how to do that? Thank you.

PS1: The list command only list the main() source of the kernel.

PS2: The remote terminal ran `make qemu-gdb` to start the QEMU, and the local terminal ran `gdb kernel` to start the debug session, following steps [here](http://zoo.cs.yale.edu/classes/cs422/2013/lec/l2-hw). I think the C source code symbols like bootmain function should be included so I should be able to step the C code in it.

Thank you again for your help!

Comment: you can try to turn off optimizations on 'c' build with '-O0' and bump up debugging level with '-g2'.

Comment: @Serge: I changed -O2 to -O0 and added -g2 after -ggdb in line 79 of Makefile, and rebuild (make clean and make qemu-gdb), but got the same error around `call bootmain'.

Comment: I noticed that your gdb version is too old, try to get 8.1. Also use -g2 at the assembly command line as well (with -ggdb).